# Show Original Values Entity Framework 7

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have an audit table that tracks Added, Deleted and Modified. I track this inside Entity Framework instead of using a Database trigger for multiple reasons  but really because we use a Process Account and I want to track what user physically made that change to that record.

I had this working in with EF 5 & I cannot remember I might have had it working in EF6 as well. Either way I am having the hardest time with EF 7 trying to capture the original values.

I noticed that when I am in the watch - I can see Original Values inside the Non-public members - so in my head I know it has to exist somewhere.

Ultimately this works inside EF earlier versions:

```
EntityEntry dbEntry; //this is actually passed in a different area just showing as an example.

foreach (string propertyName in dbEntry.OriginalValues.PropertyNames)
{
    // For updates, we only want to capture the columns that actually changed
    if (!object.Equals(dbEntry.OriginalValues.GetValue<object>(propertyName), dbEntry.CurrentValues.GetValue<object>(propertyName)))
    {
        result.Add(new TableChange()
        {
            AuditLogID = Guid.NewGuid(),
            UserID = userId,
            EventDateUTC = changeTime,
            EventType = "M",    // Modified
            TableName = tableName,
            RecordID = dbEntry.OriginalValues.GetValue<object>(keyName).ToString(),
            ColumnName = propertyName,
            OriginalValue = dbEntry.OriginalValues.GetValue<object>(propertyName) == null ? null : dbEntry.OriginalValues.GetValue<object>(propertyName).ToString(),
            NewValue = dbEntry.CurrentValues.GetValue<object>(propertyName) == null ? null : dbEntry.CurrentValues.GetValue<object>(propertyName).ToString()
         }
         );
      }
 }
```

The error I am getting is the EntityEntry does not contain a defition for OriginalValues. I am going to pull my hair out... How do I get the Original Values from a Modified Object with EF 7?

Comment: there is [DbEntityEntry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbentityentry(v=vs.113).aspx) that contains `OriginalValues`. you can get it using [DbContext.Entry<TEntity>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696578(v=vs.113).aspx) method.

Comment: @ieaglle that's EntityFramework 5/6

Comment: oh right, your answer is correct then. [PropertyEntry](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/868794f6ab99ff1681a09a2a5e307a742e9d0526/src/EntityFramework.Core/ChangeTracking/PropertyEntry%60.cs) contains `OriginalValue` and [EntityEntry](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/868794f6ab99ff1681a09a2a5e307a742e9d0526/src/EntityFramework.Core/ChangeTracking/EntityEntry.cs) contains method [Property](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/868794f6ab99ff1681a09a2a5e307a742e9d0526/src/EntityFramework.Core/ChangeTracking/EntityEntry.cs#L91) that returns `PropertyEntry`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
// using System.Reflection;
foreach (var property in dbEntry.Entity.GetType().GetTypeInfo().DeclaredProperties)
{
    var originalValue = dbEntry.Property(property.Name).OriginalValue;
    var currentValue = dbEntry.Property(property.Name).CurrentValue;
    Console.WriteLine($"{property.Name}: Original: {originalValue}, Current: {currentValue}");
}
```

Comment: What kind of syntax involving the prefix `$` is it? some kind of new feature of the C# 6.0?

Comment: @Hopeless, Yup. This is called [String Interpolation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx).

Comment: As always, error handling is advisable. `dbEntry.Property(property.Name)` will throw an InvalidOperationException if the entity class contains properties that are not included in the model, for example by way of the `[NotMapped]` annotation as shown [here](http://ef.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modeling/included-properties.html). You can instead loop over `entry.Metadata.GetProperties()` if you only want to consider properties mapped in the model. That probably should also work for [shadow properties](http://ef.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modeling/shadow-properties.html), but I didn't try.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to still use *OriginalValues*, but instead of *PropertyNames*, use *Properties*. This will make the foreach loop process types of **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.IProperty**. The *GetValues* method has an overload that accepts *IProperty*, so no changes needed in code for those calls, but you will need to change the *ColumnName* assignment from *propertyName* to *property**.**Name*.

```
foreach (var property in entityEntry.OriginalValues.Properties)
{
    if (!object.Equals(entityEntry.OriginalValues.GetValue<object>(property), 
        entityEntry.CurrentValues.GetValue<object>(property)))
    {
        result.Add(
            new AuditLog()
            {
                UserId = userId,
                EventDate = changeTime,
                EventType = "M",
                TableName = tableName,
                RecordId = entityEntry.OriginalValues.GetValue<object>(keyName).ToString(),
                ColumnName = property.Name,
                OriginalValue =
                    entityEntry.OriginalValues.GetValue<object>(property) == null
                    ? null
                    : entityEntry.OriginalValues.GetValue<object>(property).ToString(),
                NewValue = 
                    entityEntry.CurrentValues.GetValue<object>(property) == null
                    ? null
                    : entityEntry.CurrentValues.GetValue<object>(property).ToString()
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This can be resolved by this Method dbEntry.GetDatabaseValues().
Sample Code is mention below.

```
 if (dbEntry.State == System.Data.EntityState.Modified)
{
    foreach (string propertyName in dbEntry.OriginalValues.PropertyNames)
    {
    // Caputre current value 
     var originalValue = dbEntry.GetDatabaseValues().GetValue<object>(propertyName) == null ? null : dbEntry.GetDatabaseValues().GetValue<object> 
    (propertyName).ToString();
    // Caputre Updated value                    
    var currentValue = dbEntry.CurrentValues.GetValue<object>(propertyName) == null ? null : dbEntry.CurrentValues.GetValue<object>(propertyName).ToString();
        // For updates, we only want to capture the columns that actually changed
        if (!object.Equals(!object.Equals(originalValue, currentValue))
        {
            result.Add(new AuditLog()
                    {
                        AuditLogID = Guid.NewGuid(),
                        UserID = userId,
                        EventDateUTC = changeTime,
                        EventType = "M",    // Modified
                        TableName = tableName,
                        RecordID = dbEntry.OriginalValues.GetValue<object>(keyName).ToString(),
                        ColumnName = propertyName,
                        OriginalValue = originalValue,
                        NewValue = currentValue,
                    }
                );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Bad idea. This does a database query for *each* entity going through this method. Object graphs can easily contain tens of entities.