# How to resolve error when checking for field changes in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have this code to log changes during a save:

```
foreach (var property in entityEntry.OriginalValues.Properties)
{       
    if (!object.Equals(entityEntry.OriginalValues.GetValue<object>(property),
                entityEntry.CurrentValues.GetValue<object>(property)))
            {
                this.Events.Add(
                    new Event()
                    {
                        AppUserId = this._appUserProvider.CurrentAppUserId,
                        EventDate = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow,
                        EventTypeId = eventTypeId,
                        RecordId = entityEntry.OriginalValues.GetValue<int>("Id"),
                        ColumnName = property.Name,
                        OriginalValue =
                            entityEntry.OriginalValues.GetValue<object>(property) == null
                            ? null
                            : entityEntry.OriginalValues.GetValue<object>(property).ToString(),
                        NewValue =
                            entityEntry.CurrentValues.GetValue<object>(property) == null
                            ? null
                            : entityEntry.CurrentValues.GetValue<object>(property).ToString()
                    });
            }
}
```

I got this from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32597498/show-original-values-entity-framework-7)

However, I am getting an error on the first line:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Func`2[Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry,System.Int32]' to type 'System.Func`2[Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry,System.Object]'.
```

It checking the first field which is an int Id field when the error is thrown.

How do I resolve?  I don't quite understand what the issue is.

Maybe it worked in Entity Framework, but now doesn't in EntityFrameworkCore?

UPDATE: And suddenly, I realize what the issue is.  This is an entity which was added from an API call and the state set to modified, so there is no original value in the StateTracker.  So somehow I would need to get the original values to compare to check which values had changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exception is from `GetValue<object>(property)` call.

The generic type argument of `GetValue` method is expected to be the exact property type, i.e. cannot be used to get generic value as `object`.

Instead, you can use one of the `PropertyValues` object indexers for that purpose, e.g. `entityEntry.OriginalValues[property]` and `entityEntry.CurrentValues[property]`.

Regarding the update. When you attach entity instance, the `OriginalValues` and `CurrentValues` will be one and the same. In such case, instead of the `OriginalValues` property you could use the result of the `GetDatabaseValues` method call, e.g.

```
var originalValues = entityEntry.GetDatabaseValues();
```

Comment: Thanks alot , it saved me :)